# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null - HTML5

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to use HTML5 to show some UE4 scenes, but if I try to use a real server I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]

Server is running Apache 2.x (Linux Ubuntu 18.04) and mod_rewrite is enabled.

On the other hand, if I run the test server (HTML5LaunchHelper.exe) if works fine.

I've also tried 64-bit versions of browsers and enabling browser options as said in docs.

What is wrong? I'm stuck a couple of days.

**EDIT 1**

[image: Additional info]

Comment: Are you able to debug it? The null property might be getting set to something you could input as a setting.

Comment: @George can you give me some instructions on how to proceed? I'm pretty new to it.